# How do I iterate through this JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a  json of the form :

```
{
      "SentenceFacts": [
        {
          "Objective : ": "none"
        },
        {
          " Seeking a challenging position where my analytical and problem solving skills can be put in for the successful execution of the organizations projects .": "none"
        },
        {
          "Summary : ": "none"
    } ]
}
```

How can I get each name value pair in this using jQuery / JS?

I need to get the name value pairs inside the  `[ ]`

I've seen solutions suggestin `$.each()` function but that seems to work only for JSON of the form `{name:value}`.

Sorry I'm new to this....

Comment: This is  not a valid JSON

Comment: That's some crappy formatted JSON you got there, is this coming from your server or a 3rd party?

Comment: Jsonlint is a nice tool to check if your JSON is valid http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: it might be crappy, but that does not mean you cannot iterate over it ..it's still a valid object

Comment: Parse error - Expecting String on line 9

Comment: @Robert No it's invalid since there is a new line in a key

Comment: Sorry,  its an array of JSON objects

Comment: @Aneesh now i correct it

Comment: @JonKoops i'm sure the newline is a typo, remove it and its a valid object

Comment: @Robert Probably, but I tend to not assume things. Especially on Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: Me neither. Pasted the code into my dev console ..it gave syntax error, so removed a line, and it worked. Then assumed it's a typo :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
for(var i=0; i<json.SentenceFacts.length; i++) {
  var item = json.SentenceFacts[i];
  for(var prop in item) {
     // prop here is "Objective", " Seeking a challenging position ..." etc 
     console.log("key: "  , prop);     
     console.log("value: ", item[prop]);
  }
}:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.SentenceFacts.length; i++) {
    for (var key in jsonObj.SentenceFacts[i]) {
        jsonObj.SentenceFacts[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && console.log(key, jsonObj.SentenceFacts[i][key]);
    }
}
```